# What is symbolic link in laravel framework?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using **Laravel** **Framework**  for development.I want to know that what are symbolic links, and when to use them ?

Comment: Where did you find the reference to this symbolic link? Please explain what exactly you mean.

Comment: When I run php artisan command , I got this ..                                   storage
  storage:link                    Create a symbolic link from "public/storage" to "storage/app/public"

Comment: It's a "shortcut" to point one file to another. In Laravel's case, when you try to open/visit `storage/example.txt`, it will look for the `storge/app/public/example.txt` file.

Comment: Yeah it's a simple shortcut like in windows. I don't know why do they call symbolic link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In computing, a symbolic link (also symlink or soft link) is the nickname for any file that contains a reference to another file or directory in the form of an absolute or relative path and that affects pathname resolution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Further in the Laravel docs:

> **The Public Disk**
>   The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the `public` disk uses the local driver and stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#configuration

Answer (score 4):

Laravel Symbolic link is used to link storage/app/public directory with the public directory.

The easiest way to understand Symbolic link is to think a folder shortcut which we usually create in Windows. So if we add/edit/delete anything in the shortcut folder it will also reflect on the main folder and vice versa. Same thing happens in Laravel.

As per the standard, every file which is uploaded/generated using Laravel should reside into storage/app/public directory but that folder will not have full permission to be accessed by outside world.

And again as per the standard, every file which needs to be accessed by the outside world should be in the public directory.

So to keep both the standard into the consideration, a simple solution is to create a Symbolic link.

More info:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#the-public-disk
https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-storage-directory